# Angular Components interaction with Input() is not synced

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here is [the most simple example of how to use `Input()` in Angular](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#Parent-to-Child-Sharing-Data-via-Input).

I tested the exact same pattern in my code, and noticed the child property is only synced once, when child component is created, but not after.

In the example in the link, it means if `parentMessage` is changed later, the `childMessage` stays the same. That's not what I expected.
How to keep `childMessage` always identical to `parentMessage`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please can you explain the ask for close for "off-topic"?

Comment: read [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter) Read the complete page though.

Comment: And about close vote, what you are asking is not clear, may be give an example code? **Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.**

Comment: @sabithpocker I already read this paragraph but it does not seem related to my problem, or I missed something. I can elaborate on my problem, but the example provided in the link seems to cover exactly my question. What is unclear to you in my question? Please tell me what you don't understand sothat I explain it better.

Comment: The question should contain all information that is necessary for understanding the problem, without reading off-site resources. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary for code-related problems. Since you're describing the behaviour that may be needed to be investigated and debugged, it's preferable to provide a way to replicate the problem as well - a plunk, stackblitz, etc.

Comment: Even though you state that you *tested the exact same pattern in my code*, it's not evident that it is exactly the same and you didn't do any mistakes, this is what MCVE is for. *if parentMessage is changed later, the childMessage stays the same. That's not what I expected* - this is not what I would expect too, because Angular data binding doesn't work like that.